# Pytest-django won't post json data leading to assertion error. Not permission/method related

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest-django

I'm writing a test for my django online project and I'm stuck in a function that returns 201 if data is valid (it's testing if data is valid when creating a new product for the store.).

Django version 4.1.7
Django Rest Framework 3.14.0
pytest 7.2.2
pytest-django 4.5.2

The issue is that no matter what data I input in the function it always returns a 400 error. I'm sure it's not a permission issue because I've got `authenticate(is_staff=True)`, which works in the previous functions. Also, I'm able to post a "Product" both in the Admin panel and in the products url if i'm logged with an account with Staff privileges.

Here's the test_products.py code:

```
from store.models import Collection, Product
from rest_framework import status
import pytest
from model_bakery import baker


@pytest.fixture
def create_product(api_client):
    def do_create_product(product):
        return api_client.post('/store/products/', product)
    return do_create_product


@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestCreateProduct:
    def test_if_user_is_anonymous_returns_401(self, create_product):
        response = create_product({'title': 'a'})

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED

    def test_if_user_is_not_admin_returns_403(self, authenticate, create_product):
        authenticate()

        response = create_product({'title': 'a'})

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN

    def test_if_data_is_invalid_returns_400(self, authenticate, create_product):
        authenticate(is_staff=True)

        response = create_product({'title': ''})

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        assert response.data['title'] is not None

    def test_if_data_is_valid_returns_201(self, authenticate, create_product):
        authenticate(is_staff=True)

        response = create_product({
            "title": "abc",
            "slug": "abc",
            "inventory": 1,
            "unit_price": 2,
            "collection": 1
        })

        assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
        assert response.data['id'] > 0
```

conftest.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from rest_framework.test import APIClient
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def api_client():
    return APIClient()


@pytest.fixture
def authenticate(api_client):
    def do_authenticate(is_staff=False):
        return api_client.force_authenticate(user=User(is_staff=is_staff))
    return do_authenticate`
```

Product serializer:

```
`class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    images = ProductImageSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'description', 'slug', 'inventory',
                  'unit_price', 'price_with_tax', 'collection', 'images']

    price_with_tax = serializers.SerializerMethodField(
        method_name='calculate_tax')

    def calculate_tax(self, product: Product):
        return product.unit_price * Decimal(1.1)`
```

Product Viewset:

```
class ProductViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.prefetch_related('images').all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend, SearchFilter, OrderingFilter]
    filterset_class = ProductFilter
    pagination_class = DefaultPagination
    permission_classes = [IsAdminOrReadOnly]
    search_fields = ['title', 'description']
    ordering_fields = ['unit_price', 'last_update']

    def get_serializer_context(self):
        return {'request': self.request}

    def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if OrderItem.objects.filter(product_id=kwargs['pk']).count() > 0:
            return Response({'error': 'Product cannot be deleted because it is associated with an order item.'},
                            status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
        return super().destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

urls.py:

```
from rest_framework_nested import routers
from . import views


router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register('products', views.ProductViewSet, basename='products')
router.register('collections', views.CollectionViewSet)
router.register('carts', views.CartViewSet)
router.register('customers', views.CustomerViewSet)
router.register('orders', views.OrderViewSet, basename='orders')


products_router = routers.NestedDefaultRouter(
    router, 'products', lookup='product')
products_router.register('reviews', views.ReviewViewSet,
                         basename='product-reviews')
products_router.register(
    'images', views.ProductImageViewSet, basename='product_images')

carts_router = routers.NestedDefaultRouter(router, 'carts', lookup='cart')
carts_router.register('items', views.CartItemViewSet, basename='cart-items')

# URLConf
urlpatterns = router.urls + products_router.urls + carts_router.urls
```

The error displayed when running the test:

```
====================================================== FAILURES =======================================================
_________________________________ TestCreateProduct.test_if_data_is_valid_returns_201 _________________________________

self = <test_products.TestCreateProduct object at 0x103a67390>
authenticate = <function authenticate.<locals>.do_authenticate at 0x104a0e340>
create_product = <function create_product.<locals>.do_create_product at 0x104a0e480>

    def test_if_data_is_valid_returns_201(self, authenticate, create_product):
        authenticate(is_staff=True)
    
        response = create_product({
            "title": "abc",
            "slug": "abc",
            "inventory": 1,
            "unit_price": 2,
            "collection": 1
        })
    
>       assert response.status_code == status.HTTP_201_CREATED
E       assert 400 == 201
E        +  where 400 = <Response status_code=400, "application/json">.status_code
E        +  and   201 = status.HTTP_201_CREATED

store/tests/test_products.py:47: AssertionError
------------------------------------------------ Captured stderr call -------------------------------------------------
Bad Request: /store/products/
```

As mentioned, it works fine posting a object (as in the image below) in the page while logged with a staff account (john smith): (https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxajI.png)

I've been doing my best to overcome this problem. It dives me crazy because the previous tests work allright.

I`ve tried inputting different data in the test code; same data as inputted in the webpage with john smith user. I thought that maybe there's something wrong with the way I'm formatting the data in the test code. But nothing seems to work.

I hope this is enough info to explain the problem. Please let me know if you have some idea ho to solve it.

Comment: can you add the model? and one thing is that you are passing wrong URL

Comment: Hi @TanveerAhmad, 
yes I'm able to add the product as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxajI.png.
If you could point where the url wrong I'll correct it. It seems to be working fine because all previous test work, except the valid data one.

Comment: how can I identify, data is passing is correct or not. second thing is that if you are using routers then you can pass URL like this url=reverse('product-list'), product is your basename of that router, and if you get particular object then you can pass 'product-detail' using reverse